# Bind from 2 ViewModels in one XAML element

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile, binding

I am interested in trying to use information from two ViewModels in one element.
Here is my sample. At the beginning of the page I got this

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm: MainViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
```

... at one point I have an element that I need values from 2 VMs.

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CommandValueFromAnotherViewModel}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding StringValueFromCurrentViewModel}"> // This

    <TapGestureRecognizer.BindingContext>
             <vm:ViewModelBindingWithCommandValue />
    </TapGestureRecognizer.BindingContext>  

</TapGestureRecognizer>
```

My binding for the Command property works perfectly, but is there any way to set my CommandParameter value from my "MainViewModel" that contains "StringValueFromCurrentViewModel" property ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this:

```
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Name="root"/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext> 

....


<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CommandValueFromAnotherViewModel}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding StringValueFromCurrentViewModel,Source={x:Reference root}}">

<TapGestureRecognizer.BindingContext>
         <vm:ViewModelBindingWithCommandValue />
</TapGestureRecognizer.BindingContext>
```